# How can I view a list of all of the features that can be checked for using `has()` in Vim?

Tags: vimscript, macvim, nvim

How can I view a list of all of the features that can be checked for using `has()` in Vim?

I recently came to know the `has()` function for testing the presence of "features" (see below).

`:h features` doesn't show a list of features to test for.

How can I see a list of all features that I can test for using `has()`?

```
if has('gui_running')
   set background=dark
   colorscheme codedark
else
"   set termguicolors
   set t_Co=256
   set background=dark
   colorscheme codedark
endif
```

Comment: `:h feature-list` and scroll down a bit. It lists the feature that can be tested

Comment: Very useful! How did you find this help entry? Does vim support something similar to `apropos`?

Comment: I am just following the links from the help

Comment: In fact, a link to the help for `feature-list` is three lines into the help for `has()`.

Answer (score 3):

Just for information, not every possible thing that can be checked with `has()` is listed in [`:h +feature-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%2bfeature%2dlist). This  mostly documents things that may differ according to different choices done when vim has been compiled, and what systems it targets. IOW: enabled features.

To known whether Vim supports things introduced at different moment in time, like for instance *redo on insert mode cursor movement* (required for implementing ergonomic bracketing mappings), *background compilation* (are you still using plain `:make`?), some precise information in `getbufinfo()`, we need to check Vim history.

At that point, we

- either have to dig into the [`:h version7.0`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/version7.txt.html#version7%2e0),
  [`:h version8.0`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/version8.txt.html#version8%2e0),
  [`:h version9.0`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/version9.txt.html#version9%2e0)... files to find the patch that introduces what we are looking for.
- or to check `git blame` on its documentation -- fortunately, most patches document what they do/change/introduce.

(and as I never remember when features I need has been introduced, I collect them in a [dedicated file in my plugin library](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/has.vim)).

Answer (score 2):

`:help feature-list` is the only complete list of features you can test with `has("…")`.

⚠ You want `:help feature-list` (no **+**), *not* `:help +feature-list` (with **+**).  They are different!

---

There are also two incomplete lists:

`:version` lists a subset of possible features and shows which are enabled/present, and which are not.  It is ostensibly the list of options enabled when your Vim was compiled.

`:help +feature-list` (with **+**) is under the documentation for `:version`.  It ostemsibly lists the possible options you might see under `:version`

Comparing the three lists for my Vim 9.0, I found:

- 201 entries in `:help feature-list` (no **+**)
- 160 entries in `:help +feature-list` (with **+**)
- 131 entries in `:version`

Many entries in `:help +feature-list` (with **+**) and `:version` are written with punctuation that `has("…")` will not recognize (ex: `fork()` and `python3/dyn`).  There are also differences in case (ex: `GUI_Motif` in `:help +feature-list` versus `gui_motif` in `:help feature-list`).  Even after normalizing to remove those differences, neither of the lists in the two help pages is a subset of the other.

At any rate, `:help feature-list` (no **+**) is the one associated with the `has("…")` function, and has the entries written in a way that is suitable for that function.

Comment: I say "ostensibly" because the list of features shown by `:version` is clearly different from the list shown in `:help +feature-list` (right below `:version` in the help page).  Each has something the other does not have.  There seems to be a discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation in [`:help has()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#has%28%29) has a pointer to the features it can check for:

> The `{feature}` argument is a string, case is ignored.  See [`feature-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/builtin.txt.html#feature%2dlist) below.

If you then look at [`:help feature-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/builtin.txt.html#feature%2dlist), you'll see it mentions the three kinds of features that can be tested using `has()`:

> There are three types of features:
>
> 1. Features that are only supported when they have been enabled when Vim was compiled [`+feature-list`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%2Bfeature-list).
> 2. Features that are only supported when certain conditions have been met.
> 3. Beyond a certain version or at a certain version and including a specific patch. The "patch-7.4.248" feature means that the Vim version is 7.5 or later, or it is version 7.4 and patch 248 was included.

Note that `has("gui_running")` is the canonical example of a feature of kind 2. Other examples of kind 2 would be `has("vim_starting")`, `has("ttyin")` and `has("ttyout")`.

That description of the three kinds of features is followed by a thorough list of features matching kinds 1 and 2. (I won't reproduce it here, you can find it from the linked documentation or, better yet, from the `:help` system in your copy of Vim or NeoVim.)

See also [`:help +feature-list`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%2Bfeature-list), which covers compile-time options that become features (those of kind 1) in more detail, with links to what those features actually enable.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of these features with `:version`.

This will show you which is available and which is not, as well as your Vim version, compilation method and other information.

Comment: Is that a complete list of all (standardised) Vim features, or are such features added on a add-hoc basic by different Vim flavors (vim, nvim, macvim, etc.)? How does `has()` really work? Is it doing a substring search, i.e. `has('vim')` tries to match `'vim'` against all features listed by `:version`? Also, are (some of) these features generated by Vim at runtime, because `has('vim')` is true, when starting Macvim in terminal mode, but false when starting it in GUI mode?

Comment: I think you should update your question, I do not have the knowledge to give a more accurate answer.